# find a path that contains only one special edge

Tags: graph, dijkstra, greedy

I meet a question, which ask me to find a path from start node to the destination node in a undirected graph, which the minimal weight along the path is larger or equal to any other path. And there are a subset of edges are "dangerous", we cannot use more than one "dangerous" edge in the choosing path, how can we find this path in O(mlogn), m is the number of all edges and n is the number of vertex. Assume the result always exists.

if there is no dangerous path, I can use a modified version of Dijkstra Algorithm, however, I do not know how to add the "dangerous" edge. I can delete all the "dangerous" edges and only remain one, this will find the path may or may not include the remaining "dangerous" edge, and repeat this for every "dangerous" edges, however, the time complexity is too high. Can anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

- Construct a copy if the input graph with no dangerous links
- Find cheapest path through input graph
- Find first dangerous link in cheapest path
- Find cheapest path in copy graph from destination of first dangerous link to ultimate destination.
- Combine two paths into one from start to and including one dangerous link to destination with  o more dangerous links